# XML Annotation for Derived Value

Tags: java, jaxb

I know that `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` allows me to change a list of xml object to map.

may I know if is possible to compute a value during xml unmarshalling?

for example a date of birth is coming in.

and i have a age field. I wish to compute the age field when xml is unmarshalling.

Comment: You can compute anything you want. But where will you store it? Can you provide an example for the same. Your xml structure and adapter code?

Answer (score 0):

An `XmlAdapter` is used any time the representation in your object differs from the XML representation.  `XmlAdapter` gives you a place to insert custom logic.  It sounds like the perfect fit for your use case.